# Can I use a shortened "language" entry (language code) in my .bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, languages

I am using `BiblaTeX` and I have a question: As I see in nearly all types of sources in my `.bib` file I can use the entry `language`.

However all I put in their is literary displayed in my references. So can't I e.g. also use a ISO-639-1 or another [ISO code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)?

E.g.:

```
@online{SOTexBibLangIso,
    author = {Stackoverflow Tex Community},
    title = {Can I use a shortened "language" entry (language code) in my .bib file?},
    url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294703/can-i-use-a-shortened-language-entry-language-code-in-my-bib-file},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2016-02-18},
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with styles that print the name of the language in the bibliography (though I suppose there must be some). The field I find more useful is `langid`, which sets the language for hyphenation purposes.  In any event, my suggestion would be the same: either use a programming tool like `sed` (or `awk` or, etc.) or do it dynamically (but with more initial effort) with `\DeclareSourcemap`.

Comment: I suspect you mean `langid`, not `language` and if you are using `biber`, you can indeed use standard BCP47 codes.

Comment: No there is indeed `language`. So I tried to change it to `langid = {en}`, but in this way it is not shown in my references whereas it was shown when using `language`. I use `numeric` as my style.

Comment: Now it gets worse: When I add both `langid = {en}` and `language` Biber tells me: "WARN - The field 'language' in entry '/.../' cannot be null, deleting it"
And therefore the language is still not show in the references. So basically it currently only works when I only use 'language'.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to imply `language` doesn't exist, it's just that it's rarely what people want, but it seems you do ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`biblatex` distinguishes two language fields: (1) `language` and (2) `langid`. According to the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 20,

> [the `language` field holds the] language(s) of the work. Languages may be specified literally or as localization keys. If localization keys are used, the prefix `lang` is omissible.

on p. 25 we have

> [`langid`] The language id of the bibliography entry. [...] The identifier must be a language name known to the `babel`/`polyglossia` packages. This information may be used to switch hyphenation patterns and localize strings in the bibliography. Note that the language names are case sensitive.

So the `language` field is what is printed in the bibliography as the language of the work, while `langid` is used internally for `biblatex`'s language switching behaviour (it can be used to switch hyphenation in the bibliography, so words are hyphenated properly, or it might change the language-dependent  strings as well; this is controlled with the `autolang` option). Note that by default the `language` information is not printed if the language given there coincides with the main language of the document; this is controlled by the `clearlang` option and `\DeclareRedundantLanguages`.

You might for example have

```
@online{elk,
  author   = {Anne Elk},
  title    = {Über die Anatomie der Donnerechse},
  url      = {http://www.example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  date     = {2016-01-01},
  language = {german},
  langid   = {ngerman},
}
```

for a German text (`language` is `german`, `langgerman` would also be OK) following the new rules of orthography (`langid` is `ngerman`).

---

The `langid` field can only work with language identifiers known to `babel`/`polyglossia`, but per PLK's comment above Biber can deal with BCP47  language codes as well and maps them to their respective counterparts. In fact Biber will happily accept nonsense input such as `langid = {flobbel}`, but that will lead to problems with `babel` or `polyglossia` if you use anything other than `autolang=none` and the language package tries to load the unknown language `flobbel`.

---

The `language` field accepts any input, but language identifiers that `biblatex` knows are treated differently, they are translated. To be a bit more precise this works for languages defined in the currently used `.lbx` file as `lang<language>`, you can give them as `<language>` or `lang<language>`. If the bibstring is not defined in the `.lbx`, the content of the `language` field is printed as is. [You can see the languages supported by `english.lbx` here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/3.2/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx#L420), [for Dutch the list is here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/3.2/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/dutch.lbx#L406)). You can give the language identifier either with the prefix `lang` or without, `langgreek` and `greek` yield the same results.
If you use

```
language = {english},
```

in a Dutch document, you get the output "Engels" and if the document language is English we get "English".

The string `en` is not on the list of recognised language identifiers and is printed as is.

You can emulate what Biber does with the `langid` field using a sourcemap

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=language,
            match=\regexp{\Aen\Z},
            replace=\regexp{english}]
      \step[fieldsource=language,
            match=\regexp{\Ade\Z},
            replace=\regexp{german}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @rugk Please post an MWE with that problem. It should really work.

Comment: @rugk It might be nothing, but your error message says `"[english"` with `[` maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed. Stupid...
Thanks for your help. Now it works.

Comment: What's also interesting is that `language = {english}` is displayed correctly, but `language = {UKenglish}` and `language = {british}` (which are also valid according to the table) are displayed literary (= it just shows me `british` or `UKenglish`).

I'm using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, so my document is in German.

Comment: @rugk Sorry, the table was a bit of a red herring, I will change the answer accordingly, it is your `.lbx` file that ultimately decides which languages are printed using bibstrings and which are printed as is.

Comment: "red herring"? 

Comment: Ah okay: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring

Comment: And for all who don't know: The .lbx files can be found in the `tex\latex\biblatex` folder. At least this is where I found them in MiKTex: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex`

Comment: But it's still strange: 1. Why is the table not correct (I mean there it is clearly stated that this is about the "language" string) and 2. I found the `UKenglish.lbx` file: It is [a bit short](https://gist.github.com/rugk/720e3c5464457df1ed38), but it's there. And as I said it also does not work with "UKenglish".

Comment: @rugk Table 2 refers to the languages supported in the `langid` fields, i.e. the languages that `biblatex` speaks, it is a list of languages for which the `.lbx` file exists (or a mapping is provided). The languages automatically translated in the `language` field depend on the currently used `.lbx` file, only if it contains `lang<language>` is `<language>` translated, otherwise it is printed as is.

Comment: Someone a while ago on the github tracker proposed some interesting changes to standardise everything into BCP47 codes, which would be better.  However, it's a bit messy until babel/polyglossia also standardise or at least support some ISO standard language identifiers.