# How does langid field in biblatex differ from language field?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

Could someone summarise the differences in the use of the `langid` field from `language` field in `biblatex`? Documentation to `Gost` package for `bibtex` says that `langid` is a synonym of `language` but has priority over it.

Comment: The difference is explained in the answer to [Can I use a shortened “language” entry (language code) in my .bib file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294703/35864) So while the titles do not suggest it, your question is pretty much a duplicate. Is there anything you are missing in the answer there?

Comment: Of course the meaning of `langid` in the *BibTeX* style for GOST has no bearing on the meaning of the field in `biblatex`. The `biblatex-gost` documentation does not mention anything about the `langid` field being different in meaning to standard `biblatex`.

Comment: Does the question linked above answer your question? I'm very much tempted to vote to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: @moewe: I am still wondering what happens if both `language` and `langid` are provided or if only `language` or only`langid` are gived and they bear dofferent values.

Comment: OK, I have tried to make this more explicit in my answer below, please comment if you have any more questions or if you can think of any improvement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have touched upon this subject before in [Can I use a shortened “language” entry (language code) in my .bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294703/35864), but let's make the distinction a bit more specific here.

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) says (on pp. 25-26)

> `langid` field (identifier): The language id of the bibliography entry.
>   The alias `hyphenation` is provided for backwards compatibility. The
>   identifier must be a language name known to the `babel`/`polyglossia`
>   packages. This information may be used to switch hyphenation patterns
>   and localise strings in the bibliography. Note that the language names
>   are case sensitive. The languages currently supported by this package
>   are given in table 2. [...]

and (p. 20)

> `language` list (key): The language(s) of the work. Languages may be
>   specified literally or as localisation keys. If localisation keys are
>   used, the prefix `lang` is omissible.

That means that the **`langid`** field holds the localisation you want to use for the entry in the bibliography (and citation depending on your `language` option setting), it affects hyphenation patterns as well as localisation strings (the exact effect depends on the settings of the `language` and `autolang` options). Because this is an *internal* directive for `biblatex` the information must be given in a form that TeX understands, you can use `babel`/`polyglossia` language identifiers and with Biber even BCP47 language codes.

If you want to prepare a multi-language bibliography, it is recommended to provide `langid` for all entries. Only with that information can LaTeX properly switch language environments and possibly fonts and encodings to avoid errors or unwanted output.

The **`language`** list on the other hand has no special internal meaning, it just holds the language you want to see printed in the bibliography as the language of the work (in the standard styles the language is printed directly after the title, by default the option `clearlang` suppresses output of languages that match the document language). `biblatex` offers some localisation support for this ("known" languages are listed in §4.9.2.18 *Language Names*), so you can either give the language "key" (`russian`, `langrussian`) in which case `biblatex` will translate the field for you, or you can give the content verbatim in case the language is not supported (`Klingon`).

As far as `biblatex` is concerned the two fields are completely independent. They do not influence each other. And you can have only one of the two fields filled, or both, or none – and the contents of the field need not be equivalent. You can, for example, have

```
@online{elk,
  author   = {Anne Elk},
  title    = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  url      = {http://www.example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  date     = {2016-01-01},
  language = {french and latin},
  langid   = {ngerman},
}
```

Which tells `biblatex` (mistakenly) to treat the work as German (new orthography) (`langid   = {ngerman}`), hyphenation and localisation strings will be changed accordingly (depending on your `language` and `autolang` options). However, since we have `language={french and latin}` "French and Latin" will be printed as the language(s) of the work. It would of course make no sense to give two languages as `langid`, but it may very well be that you want to convey the information that a work is bilingual French and Latin.

In

```
\documentclass[ngerman,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{elk,
  author   = {Anne Elk},
  title    = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  url      = {http://www.example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  date     = {2016-01-01},
  language = {french and latin},
  langid   = {ngerman},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{elk}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

we thus get

> Elk, Anne (2016). A Theory on Brontosauruses. Französisch und Lateinisch. URL: http://www.example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf.

Note that even though the main language of the document is `british`, the information that the work is in French and Latin ("französisch und lateinisch", `language={french and latin}`) is printed in German (`langid={ngerman}`).

Comment: In multilanguage bibliographies the absence of `langid` in entries can produce  `LaTeX Error: Command ... unavailable in encoding T1`.