# Language-specific bibliography (biblatex): \language@active@arg" has an extra }

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, babel, languages

I get these warnings:

`! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. <inserted text>  \par  l.8 prenote=presecondary, postnote=postsecondary]`

`! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete. <to be read again>  \par  l.8 prenote=presecondary, postnote=postsecondary]`

I suppose the problem is something concerning the language settings of my document, especially those of the bibfile. I already read [Language settings in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493695/language-settings-in-bibliography) and [How does langid field in biblatex differ from language field?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323441/how-does-langid-field-in-biblatex-differ-from-language-field) but it didn't help me. Deleting the aux-file didn't change anything. The error occured since I included some new bib-files (formatted like the example below). One problem may be that I'm quite confused with these language options. But even deleting the language fields did not change anything!

So here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[french, english, italian, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true, french=guillemets, english=american, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, url=true, doi=true, isbn=true, eprint=true, dashed=false, 
backend=biber, sorting=nyt, maxbibnames=3, giveninits=false, clearlang=true, language=auto, 
autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{DissBib.bib}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Textausgaben, Übersetzungen, Kommentare}, prenote=preprimary, postnote=postprimary, filter=bwbibsort]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Sekundärliteratur}, keyword=bwSek, prenote=presecondary, postnote=postsecondary]

\end{document}
```

And here is the bib-file I used:

```
@collection{Amberger.2017,
 year = {2017},
 title = {Auf Utopias Spuren. Utopie und Utopieforschung. Festschrift f{\"u}r Richard Saage zum 75. Geburtstag},
 keywords = {bwSek},
 location = {Wiesbaden},
 publisher = {{Springer VS}},
 isbn = {978-3-658-14045-8},
 editor = {Amberger, Alexander and M{\"o}bius, Thomas and Saage, Richard},
 doi = {10.1007/978-3-658-14045-8},
 shorthand = {Amberger/M{\"o}bius/Saage 2017},
 language = {de},
 langid = {ngerman}
}


@incollection{Nitschke.2017,
 crossref = {Amberger.2017},
 author = {Nitschke, Peter},
 title = {Die kritische Referenz der Utopie, oder Wie sinnvoll ist die Abgrenzung zum Chiliasmus},
 keywords = {bwSek},
 pages = {161--174},
 publisher = {{Springer VS}},
 isbn = {978-3-658-14045-8},
 editor = {Amberger, Alexander and M{\"o}bius, Thomas and Saage, Richard},
 booktitle = {Auf Utopias Spuren. Utopie und Utopieforschung. Festschrift f{\"u}r Richard Saage zum 75. Geburtstag},
 location = {Wiesbaden},
 language = {de},
 keywords = {bwSek},
 shorthand = {Nitschke 2017},
 langid = {ngerman}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I try to run this MWE I get errors about `prenote=preprimary, postnote=postprimary, filter=bwbibsort` and `prenote=presecondary, postnote=postsecondary`. If I remove those probolematic options I can compile the code without error. The output looks OK as well. Please (i) make sure that the MWE does not produce unrelated errors (i.e. is as 'compilable as possible') and (ii) double check that the code *as posted* actually reproduces the error you are asking about. It may help if you additionally include (a link to) your full `.log` file.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but using the `shorthand` field to force a particular author-year citation style that `biblatex` could very well have calculated automatically from author and year is a bit against the spirit of `biblatex`. If you want slashes between author names instead of the standard comma, then there are ways to get that without hard-coding the label in `shorthand`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer(s). You're right, I forgot to remove my personal bibsort-filters and the pre-/postnotes which I'm using to create some text before and after the bibliography. 
But: I found out yesterday that the problem was the deprecated bbl.-file; I just deleted it, restarted biber.exe, et voilà: Everything is working as usual.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem cannot be reproduced with the code given in the question and the problem seems to have resolved itself after removing the temporary files.